# Intuition behind a certain proof of this inequality: $|a|+|b|+|c|-|a+b|-|a+c|-|b+c|+|a+b+c| \geq 0$

Tags: inequality, intuition, absolute-value

One textbook exercise asks to prove $$|a|+|b|+|c|-|a+b|-|a+c|-|b+c|+|a+b+c| \geq 0.$$

The textbook's solution is:

> If $a$, $b$ or $c$ is zero, the equality follows. Then, we can assume
>   $|a| \geq |b| \geq |c| > 0$.
>
> Dividing by $|a|$, the inequality is equivalent
>   to
>
> $$ 1 + |\frac{b}{a}| + |\frac{c}{a}| - |1+\frac{b}{a}| - |\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}| - |1+\frac{c}{a}| + |1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}| \geq 0 $$
>
> Since $
> \frac{b}{a} \leq 1$ and $\frac{c}{a} \leq 1$, we can
>   deduce that $|1+\frac{b}{a}| = 1+\frac{b}{a}$ and $|1+\frac{c}{a}| =
> > 1+\frac{c}{a}$.
>
> Thus, it is sufficient to prove that
>
> $$ |\frac{b}{a}| + |\frac{c}{a}| - |\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}| - (1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}) + |1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}| \geq 0 .$$
>
> Now, use the triangle inequality shows that the sum of the first three
>   terms are positive, and absolute value shows that the sum of last two
>   terms is also positive.

There may be more intuitive proofs to this, but how can one in 'some semi-logical way' arrive at this exact one?

Comment: The following is not readable for me: "Since $\frac{b}{a} \leq 1$ and $\frac{c}{a} \leq 1$,we can deduce that ..."  Please use ascii characters only-

Comment: done (I hope)...

Comment: It should be $\ge$ instead of $>$. (We have equality whenever all of $a,b,c$ are non-negative, or all ar non-positive)

Comment: thanks, fixed as well.

Comment: It looks a great deal like the inclusion-exclusion principle for three sets. It's unclear to me how they might be connected but it's the first place my intuition went. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by the triangle inequality
$$\left|\frac{b}{a}\right|+\left|\frac{c}{a}\right|\geq\left|\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}\right|$$ and
$$\left|1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}\right|\geq1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}$$ and after summing of these inequalities we are done.

The intuition behind this proof is very smooth I think: we want to delete as much as possible absolute values. We can see that it helps.

I think an easiest proof of this inequality it's a proof by using Popovici because $f(x)=|x|$ is a convex function. It's all proof!

Here is another example, how we can delete a symmetry or cyclicity, but we can 
 prove an inequality.

We'll prove  the following Schur's inequality.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
>   $$a^3+b^3+c^3-a^2b-a^2c-b^2a-b^2c-c^2a-c^2b+3abc\geq0.$$
>   Proof.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Now, we'll delete the symmetry, but we'll prove the inequality.

$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)=\sum_{cyc}a(a-b)(a-c)\geq$$
$$\geq a(a-b)(a-c)+b(b-c)(b-c)=$$
$$=(a-b)(a(a-c)-b(b-c))=(a-b)^2(a+b-c)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Thanks, but there is no ratio in the original formula, so why think of a ratio. Also a major obstacle for me seems to be not the idea of dividing by the maximum, but this: Mentally, you think it might be worthwhile to divide by the maximum and you arrive at the second form. But, once you do you might stop there thinking this form is hopeless, what would make you continue pushing with the next steps?

Comment: @weakmoons It's a standard  trick. The starting inequality is symmetric, but we make a new inequality, which is not symmetric because we want to delete a number of absolute values. I am ready to get other examples, how it works in inequalities proving.

Comment: Yes please.....

Comment: In the second example, after the first factoring out of $a$, what would make one continue as opposed to giving up on the approach?

Comment: @weakmoons It's exactly using of the idea of the symmetry deleting. The expression $a+b-c$ is not symmetric, but we knew that $a\geq b\geq c$ and we got $a+b-c\geq0$, which ends the proof.

Comment: Thanks again, now after the first factoring out of $a$ again, what makes us believe that we will be able to arrive at $(a+b-c)$? Sorry if am being thick, I am simply trying to learn...

Comment: Also the question the other way round: What signals make one fully abandon a certain approach?

Comment: Sorry but another soft question. When doing trial and error, what signals make one realize that two approaches are 'similar' and if one did not work, the other will not work either? The goal being to limit the explosion of possible things to try.

Comment: @weakmoons In general case we don't know before that we'll get something like $a+b-c$. We just try to prove inequality by this way. If we don't get a proof we'll look for another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add $|a|+|b|\ge |a+b|$ etc. to arrive at
$$\tag12|a|+2|b|+2|c|\ge |a+b|+|b+c|+|a+c|.$$
Also add $|a+b+c|\ge |a+b|+|c|$ etc. to find
$$\tag2 3|a+b+c|\ge |a+b|+|a+c|+|b+c|+|a|+|b|+|c|$$
Combining $u(1)+v(2)$ with $u,v\ge 0$ and rearranging gives
$$(2u-v)(|a|+|b|+|c|)-(u+v)(|a+b|+|b+c|+|a+c|)+3v|a+b+c|\ge0.$$
With $v=\frac13$, $u=\frac23$, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: OK, but what made you proceed like this?

Comment: As $|a|,|b|,|a+b|$ occur simultaneously with opposite signs, using the triangle inequality for $a+b$ seemed naturally. This then suggests to also have a look at the triangle inequality for $(a+b)+c$ etc. to relate $|a+b+c|$ to $|a+b|$ and $|c|$. The resulkting $(1)$ and $(29$ have all the required ingredients in them, just with the wrong coefficients, so it seems natural to combine them and see how the coefficients can be made nicer.

Comment: In one of my first (failed) tries. I used the triangle inequality, but only to remove $|a|, |b|, |a+b|$ from the formula entirely, which works but leaves a non-workably looking mess. How did you directly avoid falling into this by using the triangle inequality on $|b+c|$ and $|a+c|$ as well and adding all up?

Comment: And what about the textbook's proof steps?

Comment: @weakmoons The desired result is symmetric, hence I throw symmetry at it. -- The method of the textbook is also decent craftsmenship as it tries to exploit symmetries by "wlog-ging" and getting rid of many absolut values

Comment: Thanks. What is "wlog-ging"? And what are other heuristics that seem helpful from a first look at the formula (and why) if this failed, besides "wlog-ging"?

Comment: I was trying to reprove on paper using your suggestion. But I noticed that there may be a mistake in it? That's wrong no?
$$ |a+b+c| \geq |a+b|+|c|$$ 
The inequality is
$$ |a+b+c| \leq |a+b|+|c|$$ 
and the idea then fails?